# How does VIM perform charset conversion?

Tags: vim

I see the following paragraph on the vim documentation for the introduction of charset conversion:

```
Vim will automatically convert from one to another encoding in several places:
- When reading a file and 'fileencoding' is different from 'encoding'
- When writing a file and 'fileencoding' is different from 'encoding'
- When displaying characters and 'termencoding' is different from 'encoding'
- When reading input and 'termencoding' is different from 'encoding'
- When displaying messages and the encoding used for LC_MESSAGES differs from
  'encoding' (requires a gettext version that supports this).
- When reading a Vim script where |:scriptencoding| is different from
  'encoding'.
- When reading or writing a |viminfo| file.
```

I want to know who is converting to who? such as:

```
"When reading a file and 'fileencoding' is different from 'encoding'"
```

Is 'fileencoding' converted to 'encoding'? Or is 'encoding' converted to 'fileencoding'?

What is the relationship between the actual charset of the file and fileencoding and encoding?

If the actual charset of the file and the value of fileencoding are not equal, will the above conversion operations destroy the contents of the file?

**UPDATE:**

For example: the value of encoding is: utf-8 , vim opens a file: foo, and based on fileencodings matches a fileencoding value: sjis (assuming  i don't know the actual encoding of this file.), I edited foo and used ":wq" to save and close the vim window. If I open the foo file again, is the actualencoding of this file the sjis specified by fileencoding or the utf-8 specified by encoding when I last edited?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'encoding'` is the internal representation of any buffer text inside Vim; this is what Vim is working on. When you're dealing with different character sets (or if you don't care and work on a modern operating system), it's highly recommended to set this to `utf-8`, as the Unicode encoding ensures that *any* character can be represented and no information is lost. (And UTF-8 is the only Unicode representation that Vim internally supports; i.e. you cannot make it use a double-byte encoding like UTF-16.)

When you open a file in Vim, the list of possible encodings in [`'fileencodings'`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27fileencodings%27) (note the plural!) is considered:

> This is a list of character encodings considered when starting to edit
>   an existing file.  When a file is read, Vim tries to use the first
>   mentioned character encoding.  If an error is detected, the next one
>   in the list is tried.  When an encoding is found that works,
>   'fileencoding' is set to it.

So if a file doesn't look right, this is the option to tweak; alternatively, you can explicitly override the detection via the `++enc` argument, e.g.

```
:edit ++enc=sjis japanese.txt
```

Now, Vim has the file's source encoding (persisted in (singular!) [`'fileencoding'`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27fileencoding%27); this is needed for writing it back in the original encoding), and converts the character set (if different) to it's internal `'encoding'`. All Vim commands operate on that, and on `:write`, the conversion happens in reverse (or optionally overridden by `:w ++enc=...`).

#### Conclusions

- As long as the detected / passed encoding is right, *and* assuming the internal `'encoding'` is able to represent all read characters (guaranteed with `utf-8`), there will be no data loss.
- Likewise, as the original encoding is stored in `'fileencoding'`, writes of the file transparently convert back. Now, it could have happened that editing introduced a character that cannot be represented in the file's encoding (but you were able to edit it in because of Vim's internal Unicode encoding). Vim will then print `E513: write error, conversion failed` on writing, and you have to manually change the character(s), or choose a different target file encoding.

#### Example

A file with these Kanji characters `日本` is represented as follows in the SJIS encoding:

```
93fa 967b 0a
```

Each Kanji is stored in two bytes, and then you have the one-byte newline (LF) at the end.

With `:set encoding=utf-8`, this is represented internally as ([`g8`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/various.txt.html#g8) can tell you this):

```
e697 a5e6 9cac 0a
```

In UTF-8, each Kanji is stored in three bytes, the first Kanji is `e6 97 a5`.

Now if I edit the text, e.g. enclosing with (ASCII) parentheses, and `:write`, I get this:

```
2893 fa96 7b29 0a
```

The original SJIS encoding is restored, each Kanji is two bytes again, now with the added parentheses `28` and `29` around it.

Had I tried to edit in a `ä` character, the `:write` would have failed with the `E513` error, as that character cannot be represented in SJIS.

Comment: thanks , Your answer is very helpful to me, but I also want to know some information. If fileencoding and encoding have different values, i edited a file and saved it， is the actual encoding of the edited file fileencoding or encoding?  And  my question has been updated.

Comment: If you look closely, that's already answered. `'encoding'` is only concerned with the _internal_ representation inside Vim while editing. Its only effect on file contents is when some of the file's characters cannot be represented by it (which can be prevented altogether if you `:set encoding=utf-8`). It is only `'fileencoding'` that controls the file's encoding.